# What is the name of this "living planet" creature?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, content-identification, epic-tier

I remember from back when I played 4th edition more, that there exists within the lore some sort of Abberation creature that was described as being "a living planet, from the Far Realm".

It's supposedly a living thing, an Epic level opponent, and had some interesting lore associated with it.

I'm trying to recycle some of that lore into my 5th edition game, but I can't remember the name of this creature, or where I found it. Can anyone remember what this thing was called, and which book it was originally printed in?

Comment: [Possibly related on how to use such a creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14493/41726)

Comment: While possibly not important at all, if you are using the Forgotten Realms (a common occurence for 5e), there is existing 3rd edition lore around [Atropus](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Atropus), another planet-sized life form.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Allabar, Opener of the Way

The 4th edition book *Monster Manual 3*, page 186-187, details Allabar, Opener of the Way as a gargantuan level 30 solo soldier.

It's one of a group of beings called Star Spawn, and is a planet created by primordials and inspired to life by the gods, who feared what they created an exiled it to the Far Realm. It's probably the biggest creature in D&D 4th edition, and even the Monster Manual 3 suggests that actually fighting a planet is ludicrous.